# JSP Input value To Java Method -> HttpServletRequest gives NULL value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, servlets

*Hello Guys.* 
I have simple Storage page whichs **display all Products** from DB.
I set  to each of them with **Unique name** to change the **Amount of product**.
When i want to catch this value in Java method its **returns me null**. 
*Can you help me what i need to do to corretly catching value's in this text inputs ?*

**Controller :**

```
@Controller
public class StoragePageController extends HttpServlet {

    @GET
    @RequestMapping(value = "/storage/subamount/{id}")
    public String substractTheAmountValue(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String amount_req = request.getParameter("amount_sub_" + id);
        System.out.println(amount_req);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**JSP fragment :**

```
<c:set var="licznik" value="${recordStartCounter }" />
<div align="center">
    <table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="2">
        <c:forEach var="u" items="${productList }">
            <c:set var="licznik" value="${licznik+1}" />
            <tr onmouseover="changeTrBg(this)" onmouseout="defaultTrBg(this)">
                <td align="right"><c:out value="${licznik }" /></td>
                <td align="left"><c:out value="${u.description }" /></td>
                <td align="left"><c:out value="${u.amount }" /></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="text" name="amount_sub_${licznik}" id="amount_sub_${licznik}"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Substract the value" onclick="window.location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/storage/subamount/${licznik}'"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be having your API controller like the one given below given that your UI is posting the data to your API / Controller (assuming you are using the latest version of Spring Boot). You have a `@Get` mapping which does not accept request payload in the body.

```
@RestController
public class StoragePageController  {

@PostMapping(value = "/storage/subamount/{id}", produces = {"application/json"})
    public String substractTheAmountValue(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {

        String amount_req = id;
        System.out.println(amount_req);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Catching "ID" works for me fine, i can't catch a value in <input type="text" />
syso(id) gives me f.e. 4,
syso(amount_req) gives me null.

Comment: your inputs should have a name like `<input type='text' name='userName' value='' />`, did you try like this

Comment: also you is the UI posting the data to the controller?

Comment: It's amount value -> Integer, i need to catch from this text input value like "1234", dont matter what there will be.
I need to make catching corretly :P

Comment: I think your UI is iterating through a collection and rendering the HTML. In that case you have to use the `[]` in the names so that all the values are getting posted as an associative array. Example: `<input type="text" name="amount_sub_${licznik}" id="amount_sub[${licznik}]" />`

Comment: still have null :-/